# Opening keyboard while clicking inputField in VR (Oculus Quest 2 and XRIT)

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, oculus

I am currently developing a small app for oculus quest 2, using Unity. I've created a canvas, in which I've added a button and an InputField. By using the XR Interaction Toolkit, I am able to click on the button or the InputField with both of my controllers. However, it's still impossible to type anything into the InputField because when I click on it, any keyboard opens.

I've downloaded and explored the example project from git (https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/XR-Interaction-Toolkit-Examples) but I'm not using unity for a long time, so it looks impossible to find the settings (or script or anything else) that make it works.

Does anyone knows what should I do to open the keyboard when the InputField is clicked ? Also, will the text that I enter display in real time in the InputField ?

Thanks ! :)

EDIT : Apparently, it's not possible for the moment to use the oculus default keyboard, since the XRIT is not officially released.

Comment: I have a bug and can't edit my post (which doesn't save my first sentence) so : Hello everybody !

Comment: I have not used VR, but maybe look into [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TouchScreenKeyboard.Open.html). From what I could tell, most others build their own keyboard UI then when the InputField is open and selected they bring up their UI, then input the data directly in code.

Comment: @TEEBQNE That's what I did, thanks ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can enable the system keyboard by configuring `OVRCameraRig` Oculus features.

1. From the Hierarchy view, select `OVRCameraRig` to open settings in the Inspector view.
2. Under `OVR Manager`, in the `Quest Features` section, select `Require System Keyboard`.

[image]

[image]

For more: https://developer.oculus.com/documentation/unity/unity-keyboard-overlay/

Answer (score 0):

What @Codemaker answered here is for Oculus Integration. For XR Interaction Toolkit, you can manually enable a keyboard instance, by doing the following.

```
private TouchScreenKeyboard keyboard;

public void ShowKeyboard()
{
   keyboard = TouchScreenKeyboard.Open("", TouchScreenKeyboardType.Default);
}
```

Just add this `Showkeyboard()` under the Inputfield's `On Select ()` event. And you are done.

You can find the source [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TouchScreenKeyboard.Open.html). I tried it and it works for me.

Comment: Does this work in VR?