# How do I enable touch keyboard in Unity VR?

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I have a question if you can answer me it will delight me. How do you enable the touch screen keyboard? Is it inside the XR Interaction Toolkit?
I have no clue or whatsoever to get that touch keyboard out and use it in a input field in Unity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the touchscreen keyboard opens up on its own when you click on an InputField.

However if it doesn't, you should be able to open it manually like this in C#

```
public void OpenKeyboard()
{
     TouchScreenKeyboard.Open("");
}
```

You can learn more about the touchscreen keyboard and its properties
[right here.](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TouchScreenKeyboard.html)

Hope this helped you :)

Comment: Thank you for your time and answer :) Did help and solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can enable touch keyboard in the VR application using **XR Interaction Toolkit** and **Oculus Integration** package.

Even though Oculus supports the system keyboard in the VR apps but sometimes it won't work for the inputs like InputField.

If you want to enable a virtual keyboard using Oculus then refer to the following answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/70431161/7103882

If you want to enable a virtual keyboard using XR Interaction Toolkit then refer to the following steps:

- Clone / Download the XR-Interaction-Toolkit-Examples - https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/XR-Interaction-Toolkit-Examples/tree/master/VR/
- Open Assets/VR%20Examples/Scenes/UI Interaction.unity scene in Unity.
- Create a manifest file by clicking on Oculus -> Tools -> Create store-compatible AndroidManifest.xml
- Build and Run the project.

NB: Sometimes oculus system keyboard support won't work. So, I recommend you to try with XR Interaction Toolkit if the Oculus version is not supported.

Comment: Thank you for your time and answer :) 
I went for editing AndriodManifest.xml and it worked.
Thanks again